# How can I compare multiple tables in Bigquery and get the results in in separate columns?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have about 3 different tables in the same BigQuery dataset, and they all have the same schema. I need to compare all there tables for the presence of multiple values, and have the results listed in separate columns.

For example:
Tables: 'Luxury', 'Economy' and 'SUVs'. They all have columns for 'color', 'price' and 'size'.

I want to query all the tables to get the tables where color = 'red' or color = 'blue'.

This should only return two rows - like:

| Luxury | Economy | SUVs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| red | red | red |
|  | blue |  |

So in this case, Economy table has red and blue cars, but Luxury and SUVs have only red cars. I have tried, UNION ALL, and INNER JOIN, but they return only one row

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select * except(pos) from (
  select *, row_number() over(partition by source order by color) pos from (
    select distinct color, 'Luxury' source from Luxury union all
    select distinct color, 'Economy' source from Economy union all
    select distinct color, 'SUVs' source from SUVs 
  )
  where color in ('red', 'blue')
)
pivot (any_value(color) for source in ('Luxury', 'Economy', 'SUVs'))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is a good solution - I'll test it and let you know

Comment: I don't think the query is not very efficient - it ended up returning a a lot of null rows - which in my case was millions of empy rows, when I only needed one value. Maybe I'm not asking the right question, because all i need to know is how to find a value that is common to multiple tables in a dataset.

Comment: i think i see mistake I made when did copy paste from my env to SO. give me a sec - i will update the answer

Comment: see update! please test and let me know - it should not produce those extra rows now - but i didn't have chance to test it again - so let me know if stll needs to be fixed

Comment: Thank you Mikhail - that is absolutely brilliant!